# Dropbox API - How to access the App folder from browser?

Tags: android, dropbox-api

I was trying to use the Dropbox API to download images from my computer to my Android phone.

I started by setting up the API:
[image]

When I open `www.dropbox.com/home` the apps folder is not showing up.
I installed dropbox in my computer and synchronized and I was expecting the API apps folder to show up, but I can't seem to find it.

Where can I find the API's apps folder?
Is it possible to upload pictures to that folder from my computer?

Comment: [Cross-linking for reference: https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/API-support/Dropbox-API-How-to-access-the-App-folder-from-browser/m-p/221146#M11731 ]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I've used the Android Dropbox API, the folder only appears when you use the Dropbox SDK within your app to connect your account.

Comment: Oh, so in order to have access to the folders I must set it to "Full Dropbox"?

Comment: No, the app folder option should be OK, but the folder will only be created once you've connected an app to your Dropbox account using the Android API. The full Dropbox option sounds like it might be a better fit as you can use pre-existing folders in your Dropbox account, if that makes sense.

Comment: Thanks! I will give it a try and I will let you know